# Find all combinations among levels of a factor and output to list of data frames

Tags: r, list, combinations, lapply

I have a data frame like so:

```
 set.seed(540)
 df<- data.frame(site= c(rep(1, 30), rep(2,30)), 
            season= c(rep("wet", 20), rep("dry",10), rep("wet",16), rep("dry", 14)),
            plot= c(rep("A",5), rep("B",3), rep("C", 6), rep("D", 6),rep("E", 2), rep("F", 3),rep("G", 4), rep("H", 1),
                    rep("I",3), rep("J",10), rep("K", 1), rep("L", 1),rep("M", 2), rep("N", 3),rep("O", 6), rep("P", 4)), 
            plantsp= sample(1:100,60, replace= TRUE), 
            lepsp= sample(1:100,60,replace= TRUE), 
            psitsp= sample(1:100,60,replace= TRUE))
df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)
df$plantsp<-paste('plantsp', df$plantsp, sep='_')
df$lepsp<-paste('lepsp', df$lepsp, sep='_')
df$psitsp<-paste('psitsp', df$psitsp, sep='_')
df$paste1<- paste(df$varX, df$varY, sep='_')
df$paste3<- paste(df$varZ, df$varY, df$varZ, sep="_")
```

Interactions sampled within plots `plot`  within a given location `site` and `season`. I need to subset plots nested within each `site` and `season`. Within each `site` and `season` subset, I need to apply a function that will subset a data frame for each plot combination. Each data frame will be put into a list. Combinations are not considered different if the order varies (ie. 1_2 is the same as 2_1) and 2 levels are the grouping size for the combination. I would prefer a grouping size argument that is adjustable so that I may change how many levels are grouped.

I have tried the following:

```
## Create function that generates all possible combinations of 2 plots within each `sub`
combns<- combn(unique(levels(df$plot)), 2, simplify=FALSE)

## Nest data
myList <- 
  df %>% 
  group_by(season, site) %>% 
  do(sub_group=data.frame(.)) %>% 
  select(sub_group) %>% 
  map(combns)
```

Example combinations for this data frame would be:

```
#All combinations of levels within plot when nesting within site=1 and season=wet
subGroup1_comb1<- df[df$plot == "A" | df$plot == "B", ]
subGroup1_comb2<- df[df$plot == "A" | df$plot == "C", ]
subGroup1_comb3<- df[df$plot == "A" | df$plot == "D", ]
subGroup1_comb4<- df[df$plot == "B" | df$plot == "C", ]
subGroup1_comb5<- df[df$plot == "B" | df$plot == "D", ]
subGroup1_comb6<- df[df$plot == "C" | df$plot == "D", ]

#All combinations of levels within plot when nesting within site=1 and season=dry
subGroup2_comb1<- df[df$plot == "E" | df$plot == "F", ]
subGroup2_comb2<- df[df$plot == "E" | df$plot == "G", ]
subGroup2_comb3<- df[df$plot == "E" | df$plot == "H", ]
subGroup2_comb4<- df[df$plot == "F" | df$plot == "G", ]
subGroup2_comb5<- df[df$plot == "F" | df$plot == "H", ]
subGroup2_comb6<- df[df$var3 == "G" | df$plot == "H", ]

#All combinations of levels within plot when nesting within season=2 and site=wet
subGroup3_comb1<- df[df$plot == "I" | df$plot == "J", ]
subGroup3_comb2<- df[df$plot == "I" | df$plot == "K", ]
subGroup3_comb3<- df[df$plot == "I" | df$plot == "L", ]
subGroup3_comb4<- df[df$plot == "I" | df$plot == "M", ]
subGroup3_comb5<- df[df$plot == "J" | df$plot == "K", ]
subGroup3_comb6<- df[df$plot == "J" | df$plot == "L", ]
subGroup3_comb7<- df[df$plot == "J" | df$plot == "M", ]
subGroup3_comb8<- df[df$plot == "K" | df$plot == "L", ]
subGroup3_comb9<- df[df$plot == "K" | df$plot == "M", ]
subGroup3_comb10<- df[df$plot == "M" | df$plot == "L", ]


#All combinations of levels within plot when nesting within site=2 and season=dry
subGroup4_comb1<- df[df$plot == "M" | df$plot == "N", ]
subGroup4_comb2<- df[df$plot == "M" | df$plot == "O", ]
subGroup4_comb3<- df[df$plot == "M" | df$plot == "P", ]
subGroup4_comb4<- df[df$plot == "N" | df$plot == "O", ]
subGroup4_comb5<- df[df$plot == "N" | df$plot == "P", ]
subGroup4_comb6<- df[df$plot == "O" | df$plot == "P", ]
```

The result output for  this example  would be:

```
myList<-list(subGroup1_comb1,
subGroup1_comb2,
subGroup1_comb3,
subGroup1_comb4,
subGroup1_comb5,
subGroup1_comb6,
subGroup2_comb1,
subGroup2_comb2,
subGroup2_comb3,
subGroup2_comb4,
subGroup2_comb5,
subGroup2_comb6,
subGroup3_comb1,
subGroup3_comb2,
subGroup3_comb3,
subGroup3_comb4,
subGroup3_comb5,
subGroup3_comb6,
subGroup3_comb7,
subGroup3_comb8,
subGroup3_comb9,
subGroup3_comb10,
subGroup4_comb1,
subGroup4_comb2,
subGroup4_comb3,
subGroup4_comb4,
subGroup4_comb5,
subGroup4_comb6)
```

Comment: Do you need `split(df, list(df$var1, df$var2))` ?

Comment: What's the point of `VarX`, `VarY`, and `VarZ`? And `paste1` and `paste3`? Your text doesn't mention them at all. If they're irrelevant to the question, I'd suggest deleting them.

Comment: Also, when I try to run your example code, the `combn` line gives an error that `n < m`. I think after you run `as.character`, `levels` doesn't return anything. When I correct that (delete the `levels()`), your `#Nest data` give me `Error: Index 1 must have length 1`...

Comment: `paste1` and `paste3` represent interactions collected within those plots. They need to be included because the aggregate of these interactions among two plots will later be used for pairwise comparisons to calculate beta diversity.  For now, I need to go from a data frame like in the example, to a list of data frames that provides all possible plot combinations so that I may apply these functions.

Comment: @RonakShah the split function splits on site and season but does not make a separate data frame for each unique  plot combination within a given site and season

Answer (score 0):

It is not the most clean solution, ideally code would be less repetitive and iterate through some loop.

```
# Subset for each site, and season
sub1<- df[df$site == "1" & df$season == "wet", ]
plotLev1<-unique(sub1$plot)

sub2<- df[df$site == "1" & df$season == "dry", ]
plotLev2<-unique(sub2$plot)

sub3<- df[df$site == "2" & df$season == "wet", ]
plotLev3<-unique(sub3$plot)

sub4<- df[df$site == "2" & df$season == "dry", ]
plotLev4<-unique(sub4$plot)

## Generate all combinations of plots
comb1 <- combn(plotLev1, 2, simplify=FALSE)
comb2 <- combn(plotLev2, 2, simplify=FALSE)
comb3 <- combn(plotLev3, 2, simplify=FALSE)
comb4 <- combn(plotLev4, 2, simplify=FALSE)

## get list of data frames for each plot combo
myList1 <- lapply(comb1, function(x) sub1[sub1[,"plot"] %in% x, ])
myList1

myList2 <- lapply(comb2, function(x) sub2[sub2[,"plot"] %in% x, ])
myList2

myList3 <- lapply(comb3, function(x) sub3[sub3[,"plot"] %in% x, ])
myList3

myList4 <- lapply(comb4, function(x) sub4[sub4[,"plot"] %in% x, ])
myList4
```